# How can I set thread in PowerShell with executable scriptblock and ApartmentState argument?

Tags: powershell, clipboard, apartments

How can I set thread and start it with some executable code with `ApartmentState = "STA"`? I just find this method but I don't know how I can pass my scriptblock to it.

```
$r = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspace()
$r.ApartmentState = 'STA'
$r.Open()
```

I need to get clipboard text in this thread, like this:

```
$getclipboardtext = [System.Windows.Clipboard]::GetText()
$getclipboardtext | Out-File c:\examplepath
```

I also tried `Start-Job`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the runspace in a PowerShell instance (see [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/11/26/beginning-use-of-powershell-runspaces-part-1/)):

```
$ps = [PowerShell]::Create()
$ps.Runspace = $r
[void]$ps.AddScript($sb)
$ps.Invoke()
$ps.Dispose()
```

where `$r` is the runspace you opened and `$sb` is the scriptblock you want to execute.

You also have an error in your scriptblock. The `Clipboard` class is part of the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace, so it's `System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard`, not `System.Windows.Clipboard`. Plus, you need to load the respective assembly first.

Full example:

```
$sb = {
  Add-Type -Assembly 'System.Windows.Forms'
  [Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::GetText() | Out-File 'C:\path\to\output.txt'
}

$ps = [PowerShell]::Create()
$ps.Runspace = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspace()
$ps.Runspace.ApartmentState = 'STA'
$ps.Runspace.Open()
[void]$ps.AddScript($sb)
$ps.Invoke()
$ps.Dispose()
```

Comment: tnks for your answer. and can u tell me how to close this thread and mange it like suspend or smth like this .

Comment: Please see the Scripting Guy blog I linked to in my answer. Post a new question if that doesn't help.